# How do I remove the text "DE GRUYTER" from the header?

Tags: overleaf

In Overlead, I am using a dgruyter.sty package and I cannot find the place that displays the header text.
It looks like this:
[image]
and
[image]

I've done a search in all the folders but I can't remove it. Incidentally, why is the number and "references" written in the header? I can't find that either.

Comment: I do not think the license allow any modification of the package. `%% This file is part of the dgruyter package for preparing
%% books for Walter de Gruyter GmbH.
%% 
%%       Copyright (C) 2015, 2016, 2017 Walter de Gruyter GmbH`

Comment: Oh no! I've been editing it all along for my article.

Comment: No problem if you publish through them.

Comment: You may try adding `\pagetyle{myheadings}` in the preamble of the document, and adding `\thispagetyle{myheadings}` after `\maketitle`. If you prefer, you can replace `myheadings` in the  page style with `empty`.

Comment: @user94293 Yes, this did get rid of all text in the header and it is probably the only solution if I want to continue using this template. However, I wouldn't be able to put any information in the header, such as the journal name, volume and issue, etc. That's not ideal. But thank you for your help with my question.